# Exception thrown while binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse)

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

**Detail Error: IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' for Saml2SecurityToken. Inner exception: '[PII of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.**

I've got a problem and I'm not sure it came from IdP or not. After IdP authenticated user and verified the authorization, the IdP generates the SAML assertion, that have format like this:

`````
                xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                ID="..."
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant=""
                Destination="des..."
                InResponseTo="..."
                >
    <saml:Issuer>https://idp.domain</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#...">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>...</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>...</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    ID="_26df0e27-891c-4c9c-abec-ddb87a888543"
                    Version="2.0"
                    IssueInstant=""
                    >
        <saml:Issuer>https://idp.domain</saml:Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" />
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter=""
                                              Recipient="des..."
                                              InResponseTo="..."
                                              />
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore=""
                         NotOnOrAfter=""
                         >
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>https://www.valid.audience</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant=""
                             SessionNotOnOrAfter=""
                             SessionIndex=""
                             >
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="or_email"
                            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                            >
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string" />
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="login_id"
                            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                            >
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">example</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>````

In subject tag, you can see this: **<saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" />** and I wonder: Does this reason cause errors?

Thank you for your helps!

I tried to compare this assertion with the others, which was succeeded and I think **<saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" />** is the problem. In the successful assertions, this tag goes like **<saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">{some-thing-like-this}</saml:NameID>**
`````

Answer (score 0):

.NET default hide the cause of such security errors. You can add this line of code in the startup to find the cause:

```
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

Like this https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L33